# For what values of $x$ does the series $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{(\ln x)^{\ln n}}$ converge?

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, sequences-and-series, proof-verification

I have to study the values of $x$ for which $$\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{(\ln x)^{\ln n}}$$ converges.

First we say that we must have $x>0$. Then, I have started by rewriting the series as

$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{e^{\ln\ln x\ln n}} = \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{n^{\ln\ln x}}.$$

It converges if $\ln\ln x >1$. So it converges for $x>e^e$. Is my reasoning correct?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is true that $(\ln x)^{\ln n} = n^{\ln \ln x}$, hence it should hold when $\ln \ln x > 1$, which happens, as you correctly wrote, when $x>e^e$.

Comment: Do you think I should use absolute value somewhere? (Because the series otherwise doesn't have always positive terms.)

Comment: No, $n^{\ln \ln x}$ is always positive when it is defined (in the reals).